# How to convert a date-format string into a NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a NSString that contains this value:

```
@"19 Oct 2013 18:00:54 GMT"
```

I want to use that data to convert into a NSDate. I use this code to do so:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *eventDate=[dateFormat dateFromString:self.informationPublishDate];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", eventDate);
```

The problem here is that this code outputs this:

```
2012-12-23 13:00:51 EST
```

It outputs this value for events of all dates and times, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Isn't this because you set `eventDate` and output `tsunamiDate`?

Comment: sorry about that...I kinda wanted to keep the app secret, and I forgot to change that variable. It's been edited now (it was a typo).

Comment: Understand that the NSLog of an NSDate prints the date in UTC timezone.  And using YYYY instead of yyyy causes all sorts of mysterious effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is wrong. You are missing an `M` and it should be `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`

The correct one is

```
@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
```

Comment: Converting the YYYY to yyyy solved it. Thanks so much. This has been bothering me for a while.